# Openalayers : How to know map container id's from map object

Tags: javascript, openlayers

After rendering multiple maps using openlayers , I want check which map is in which div .

```
 if (!this.previewMapLoaded) {
      this.mapService.loadMap('previewmap', 'preview', extent);

  if (!this.mainMapLoaded) {
      this.mapService.loadMap('mainmap', extent);
```

is there any method like ,

```
this.map.getContainer()
```

or something similar to this ?

Comment: map.getTarget() or map.getTargetElement()

Comment: map.getViewport() also return a div